# Python Tkinter Treeview - color rows individually based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, treeview, background-color

I'm building a GUI with tkinter and was wondering if there is way to set a background color for rows that meet a certain criteria.

A simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=np.random.randint(1, 6, size=4),
    B=np.random.randint(1, 10, size=4),
    C=np.random.randint(1, 12, size=4),
    D=np.random.randint(1, 9, size=4)
))

# subset of dataframe
df_tree = df[["A","B"]]

# Treeview
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Example")
root.geometry('600x600')
root.pack_propagate(False)

# Frame for Treeview
TV_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root)
TV_frame.place(height=580, width = 580, rely=0.02, relx=0.02)

# Build Tree with df_tree
Tree = ttk.Treeview(TV_frame)
Tree.place(relheight=0.96, rely=0.01, relx = 0.01, relwidth=0.98)

treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(TV_frame, orient = "vertical", command = Tree.yview)
treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(TV_frame, orient = "horizontal", command = Tree.xview)

Tree.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set, yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)
treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y")

#Print tree in tkinter
Tree["column"] = list(df_tree.columns)
Tree["show"] = "headings"

for column_1 in Tree["columns"]:
    Tree.heading(column_1, text=column_1)

df_rows_1 = df_tree.to_numpy().tolist()

for row_1 in df_rows_1:
    Tree.insert("", "end", values = row_1)

root.mainloop()
```

E.g. I would be interested to have a red background for all rows where Column C is greater than 6.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Setting the color for a row is covered in existing documentation. It's not clear why you need our help.

Answer (score 1):

The tree.insert method will take an argument called "tags". You can use this to define the color of a treeview row.

To do this, add the following line to your code, underneath the lines in which you pack the treeview scrollbars:

```
Tree.tag_configure('tag_name', background="red")
```

This creates one tag you can use to influence the background color of treeview rows. You can have multiple tags if you want to add multiple colors to your rows. You use these tags when inserting rows into your tree like this:

```
Tree.insert("", "end", values = row_1, tags='tag_name')
```

In your case, you might do something like:

```
for row_1 in df_rows_1:
    if column C > 6:
        Tree.insert("", "end", values = row_1, tags='tag_for_red')
    else:
        Tree.insert("", "end", values = row_1, tags='tag_for_other_color')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Tree.tag_configure("tagName", background="Blue")
Tree.item("rowNum", tags=("tagName"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.